# Cannot access this.props as id in firebase firestore request (react native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, this, native

I have this Diet screen, where I want to output diet name and forbidden ingredients for that diet. Diet name is passed to Diet screen as route.params.

```
export default function DietScreen({ route }) {
  const { dietName } = route.params;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Diet Screen</Text>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(dietName)}</Text>
      <Ingredients dietName={JSON.stringify(dietName)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

It outputs the diet name correctly but when I want to open the ingredients from firestore in Ingredients component I get an error: `"undefined is not an object(evaluating 'doc.data().forbidden_ingredients')"`

```
class Ingredients extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ingredients: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
     firestore()
        .collection('Diets')
        .doc(this.props.dietName)
        .onSnapshot(doc =>
          this.setState({
            ingredients: doc.data().forbidden_ingredients,
          })
        );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  renderIngredients = () => {
    return this.state.ingredients.map(ingredient => (
      <Text key={ingredient}>{ingredient}</Text>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderIngredients()}</View>;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using diet name as an id. When I console.log `this.props.dietName` I get the correct desired name logged. If I use the diet name directly like `.doc("vegetarian")` I get the correct ingredient list. But for some reason when I `this.props.dietName` does not work as id in firestore request.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `JSON.stringify` should be removed from `DietScreen` function.
Instead of:

```
<Ingredients dietName={JSON.stringify(dietName)}  />
```

I think it should be:

```
<Ingredients dietName={dietName} />
```

Unfortunately I don't have playground in reactjs, however if I understand correctly `dietName` is a string, so generally in JS when you use `JSON.stringify` on string will get string with quotation marks.

We can test this like this:

```
const params = {dietName: "one"} 
const  {dietName}  = params;
const dietNameParam = JSON.stringify(dietName);
console.log(`dietNameParam is ${dietNameParam} and it's lenght is ${dietNameParam.length}`);
console.log(`while dietName is ${dietName} and it's lenght is ${dietName.length}`);
```

If you run it somewhere, like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (just paste the code in demo window and hit run). You will see that the string generated by `JSON.stringify` is longer.